# Is the OneClick tag necessary? Seems to have mostly questions about ClickOnce

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Looks like all questions in the [oneclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oneclick) tag are really talking about [clickonce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clickonce). Should these be merged?

As a side note, question quality appears to be rather low, but maybe that's expected if you are confusing OneClick and ClickOnce.

Comment: LGTM. Can you suggest a synonym?

Comment: The OneClick tag only seems to have 34 questions on it.  So will be quick to clean up by hand.